# How do I print '-e' with echo?

Tags: shell, echo

I know that `echo -e` is not an ordinary command. I have tried `echo '-e'` and `echo \-e` but they still don`t work.

Comment: What do you mean with 'not an ordinary command line'? `echo` is usually a shell builtin, but there is usually also `/usr/bin/echo`. The `-e` is not POSIX, but available e.g. with bash. Please give more details what you mean with 'they still don't work'. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I want to print -e using echo. Any suggestions?

Comment: consider using printf, it's more portable.

Comment: Curiously enough, `echo -- -e` doesn't work either. Conventionally (with GNU utilities at least) the double dash indicates the end of options, with the rest being kept as literal arguments.

Comment: @WilCooley, not a huge surprise -- given that `echo` by its nature needs to treat arguments as data, _including those that start with dashes_, each and every extension is by its nature a deviation from standard-defined behavior (something that a standards-compliant `echo` would emit to the screen gracefully, but an extended `echo` does not).

Comment: `echo` madness again. If people would only use `printf` and never look back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- with newline

  ```
  echo -en '-e\n'
  ```
- without newline

  ```
  echo -e '-e\c'
  ```
- with spaces around:

  ```
  echo '-e '
  echo ' -e'
  ```
- using backspace (thanks to Joseph R.):

  ```
  echo -e ' \b-e'
  ```

  (it does output SPC BS - e LF, but when sent to a terminal that's rendered as `-e` as BS moves the cursor back one column to the left causing `-` to overwrite the SPC)

The behaviour of `bash`'s `echo` builtin may depend on bash version. It also depends on the environment (`POSIXLY_CORRECT`, `SHELLOPTS` and `BASHOPTS` variables), the options (`posix`, `xpg_echo`), the build options and `argv[0]` (`sh` vs `bash`). Here tested with `GNU bash 4.2.53(1)`, default build, default options, empty environment, invoked as `bash`. Works also with `zsh 5.0.5`.

Comment: Why do these ugly-to-the-bone obfuscated "workarounds" receive upvotes? Charles Duffy below has the proper answer: use printf and forget about such problems once and for all.

Comment: Also, `echo -e "\0-e"`.

Comment: Jens: because the OP asked how to do it with the `echo` command.  Attitude not necessary.

Comment: @ctc - What's the logic behind that answer? I'm not questioning whether it works (with the specific versions of `echo` tested), but it is a bit... interesting... given as NULs act as terminators when given in C strings; I'm curious as to whether it's an accident of implementation or defined behavior that it functions as given.

Comment: `echo -e ' \b-e'` outputs space-backspace-dash-e. Only displayed in a terminal will it give you the illusion that it is dash-e.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, `echo -e "\0-e"` does output `NUL-dash-e`. It's just that terminals ignore that NUL character (NULs even used to be sent to some terminals (that did not support flow control) to give them time to do other long things like a carriage return. See the section under _Delays and Padding_ in `terminfo(5)`.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, ahh. I'm a touch disappointed that I read that incorrectly. That said, using this trick will have ill effects when emitting output anything but a terminal -- *especially* in cases (like shell command substitutions) where its output is stored in a C string.

Answer (score 25):

The best solution is not to use `echo`, but to use `printf` instead.

```
printf '%s\n' -e
```

This works with arbitrary variables:

```
var=-e
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

...meaning you don't need to do any special preparation/modification elsewhere in your code based on the knowledge that a value will be `echo`d.

---

Incidentally, [the POSIX shell command specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) acknowledges that it is unportable as implemented, and contains a note on that subject:

> It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both -n (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.
>
> The printf utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the echo utility as follows (assuming that IFS has its standard value or is unset):
>
> The historic System V echo and the requirements on XSI implementations in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 are equivalent to:
>
> ```
> printf "%b\n" "$*"
> ```
>
> The BSD echo is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if [ "X$1" = "X-n" ]
> then
>     shift
>     printf "%s" "$*"
> else
>     printf "%s\n" "$*"
> fi
> ```
>
> **New applications are encouraged to use printf instead of echo.**

(Emphasis added).

---

That said, on GNU systems, an alternative exists: Requesting standards-compliant behavior.

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -e
-e
```

Comment: Interestingly, the POSIX note does say that `echo -e` is portable. It says `-n` must be avoided, and escape sequences must be avoided. `echo -e` avoids both. But as you indicate in the last part of your answer, on GNU systems, `echo` doesn't bother to conform to POSIX at all by default, and POSIX only notes portability across POSIX systems.

Comment: @hvd, I don't see `-e` covered in the portion of the spec that I linked to. Could you provide a link or citation that covers it?

Comment: It's the lack of a mention that says it. :) It lists the uses that aren't portable, and `-e` isn't mentioned, so `-e` is portable (again, across POSIX systems). To be fair, what you quoted is informative, but the normative text says the same thing: "If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined."

Comment: @hvd, rather the contrary. To perform as specified, `echo` needs to emit all arguments with no behavior defined in a contrary way by the standard. Thus -- unlike almost all other command-line tools covered by the POSIX spec -- `echo` actually _specifies_ behavior for arguments not given: Printing them. There is no room for adding new flags without breaking specification.

Comment: @hvd, ...for that matter, see the `OPTIONS` section, where it's set out in black and white: `Implementations shall not support any options`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. The OP is interested in printing the string "-e". On POSIX-conforming systems, `echo -e` does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry, then -- I quite misunderstood your argument; we are indeed in violent agreement.

Comment: I can see how my comments could be read the way you read them, sorry for not having been clearer. Glad it's resolved. :)

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `echo`'s `-e` with the ASCII codes for the characters:

```
$ /bin/echo -e '\055'e
-e
```

`055` is the octal ASCII number for `-` (see `man ascii` for quick reference).

Comment: `/bin/echo` is indeed POSIX-specified. However, its interpretation of octal escape sequences is an XSI extension to the baseline specification.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, I misspoke. +1 for printf (my first thought as well). Given that `-e` is an extension, however, is there a way to force pure POSIX behaviour on `echo`? That would eliminate all uncertainty over this, I think.

Comment: Actually, yes! Exporting `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` will result in POSIX-compliant behavior for GNU's `/bin/echo`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, good to know to keep your scripts portable and "homebrew-Linux-independent" (i. e. also working on a pro workstation at work).

Comment: @Kusalananda forgot about this.

Comment: With GNU `echo`, you can do `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -e` as POSIX currently requires `echo -e` to output `-e<newline>`.

Answer (score 3):

While the obvious, standard and recommended solution is to use `printf`, to do it with `echo` can be quite tricky depending on the implementation (not as tricky as for `-n` though).

### POSIX.2017 compliant `echo`s

POSIX *requires* `echo -e` to output `-e<newline>`. So it's just

```
echo -e
```

there. POSIX compliant `echo`s in that regard (most of them are not POSIX  compliant in other regards, the POSIX spec is close to useless when it comes to `echo`) include:

- the `echo` builtin of `bash` when both the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options have been enabled (at runtime or build time like for the `/bin/sh` of Apple macOS). `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo` (the `posix` option can also be enabled if invoked as `sh` or when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` or `SHELLOPTS=posix` is in the environment).
- the `/bin/echo` of certified UNIX systems (AIX, macOS, Solaris at least) and most BSDs
- the `echo` builtin of `dash`, `ksh88`, the Bourne shell, csh, tcsh, posh, rc, es, akanga
- GNU `echo` (`/bin/echo` on GNU systems) when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.
- the `echo` builtin of `mksh` and some other pdksh-derives when their `posix` option is enabled.
- the `echo` builtin of `yash` when `$ECHO_STYLE` is either unset or one of `SYSV`, `XSI`, `BSD`, `DASH`, `RAW`

### implementations that support `-e`

Includes `echo` of research Unix V8 (where it comes from), GNU, busybox, the `echo` builtin of `bash`, `zsh`, `pdksh` and derivatives, `fish`, some `ash`-based shells like busybox `sh` or the `sh` of some BSDs, recent versions of `ksh93` (on some systems, and with some values of `$PATH`) with their default settings, `yash` with `$ECHO_STYLE` one of `GNU` or `ZSH`:

```
echo -e '-e\n\c'
```

The implementations that support `-e` invariably support `-n`, so:

```
echo -ne '-e\n'
```

would work as well.

### zsh

`zsh`'s `echo` is the only implementation that I know that supports an end-of-option marker (`-`).

```
echo - -e
```

Making it the only Bourne-like shell `echo` that can output arbitrary data (also because it's the only one that supports NUL bytes in its variables and the arguments of its builtins) with `echo -E - "$data"`)

Except for the NUL-byte issue, other implementations that can output arbitrary data are FreeBSD or macOS `/bin/echo` where you can do:

```
/bin/echo "$data
\c"
```

(in that implementation, `\c` is only recognized at the end, and no other escape sequence is supported).

And `yash`'s:

```
ECHO_STYLE=RAW echo "$data"
```

(though note that `yash` variables can only hold text, so not arbitrary byte sequences in locales where not all sequences of bytes can form valid characters like in those using UTF-8 as their charmap).

Answer (score 2):

Use `-n` to avoid newline:

```
$ echo -n - && echo e
-e
```

Comment: That won't work in `zsh` where `-` is the end of option delimiter or on all the `echo` implementations that don't support `-n` (those that support `-e` also support `-n` though)