# echo version or not to be

Tags: shell, echo

In the line of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906590/echo-version-doesnt-works I need to know the version of `echo`

```bsh
$ type -a echo | cut -d " " -f 3- | xargs -d '\n'
a shell builtin /usr/bin/echo /bin/echo
$ /usr/bin/echo -v
-v
$ /bin/echo -v
-v
```

Comment: As per the linked question, the version of (GNU) echo is found using `/bin/echo --version`, not `/bin/echo -v`

Comment: What doesn't work with the suggested solution to use the binary(**!**) and then `--version`?

Comment: @user4556274 Calling directly the binary combined with this option works

Comment: I actually have an XY problem where I try to find why colors does not print on my server but prints locally. And one of my guess was the echo version. Which is not. So I will open a new question about the problem precisely

Comment: Actually nevermind, `printf` is more coherent than `echo` so now it prints color wherever I execute it. So if someone has the idea to go here for this problem: Heres your solution

Answer (score 2):

Standard `echo` doesn't take any options (or with XSI extensions, only recognizes the `-n` argument). In many cases, the `echo` you use is one built in to the shell, and in none of the shells I tested, the builtin `echo` recognizes `--version`. They do variously recognize at least `-e`, `-E`, `-n` though. The only `echo` I found that recognizes `--version` is the one from GNU coreutils, i.e. the one installed at `/bin/echo` on many Linux systems.

So, in most cases, the question of recognizing the version of `echo` comes down to recognizing the shell you're running. Or running `/bin/echo`, if you know you're on a system where that's GNU, and not e.g. Busybox. Also, as seen on the [man page, the GNU coreutils version only supports `--version`, not `-v` or `-V`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/coreutils/echo.1.en.html).

---

But in general, if you're trying to get something done, you don't need to depend on the particular version of something, just the supported functionality. And when looked at that way, it's easier to just use `printf` rather than `echo`.

If you want to print a string as-is, use

```
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

If you want to process backslash-escapes in the string, use

```
printf "%b\n" "$var"
```

And if you want to skip the final newline, remove the `\n` from the first argument.

See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)  and [How do I print '-e' with echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168095/170373)

Comment: I replaced `echo -n` with `printf "%b"` and `echo` with `printf "%b\n"` and it works same as echo

Comment: @user4556274 gave the right solution, but he didn't created an answer. So maybe you could edit your one to suggest to use `--version` with the binary path instead of just `-v`. Or maybe he could

Comment: It's the other way round. non-XSI `echo`s are not guaranteed not to support options, XSI ones are. That is a Unix compliant `echo` is required not to support option, while POSIX-only ones may support `-n` ([will be extended to `-e`/`-n`/`-E` and combinations thereof in the next version of the standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1222#c4375)).

Comment: Note that the `echo` from GNU coreutils outputs `--version<newline>` as required by POSIX when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.

Comment: toybox `echo` (Android) also support `--version` (and `--help` and `--`, I'll update that Q&A you linked). The `echo` builtin of the Android shell (mksh) doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Springboarding off @ilkkachu's answer:

On my macOS 10.15 laptop using `zsh`, I get the following:

```
% which echo
echo: shell built-in command 

% whereis echo
/bin/echo

% /bin/echo --version
--version
```

Which is explained by referring to `man echo`: Apple packages a 2002 BSD version of `echo` in their new laptops - it supports only the `-n` argument. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 `echo` programs: from GNU Bash and from GNU Coreutils.

**`echo` from GNU Bash**

- to find out `echo` (GNU Bash) you could using this commands `help` or `help echo`
- to run `echo` (GNU Bash) just try using `echo`

  ```bash
  echo "Hello World"
  echo -e "line 1\ttab\nline2"
  echo --help    # will return error "--help"
  echo --version # will return error "--version"
  help echo
  ```
- to know the Bash version try `bash --version`, there is no echo GNU Bash version

**`echo` from GNU Coreutils**

- to find out echo (GNU Coreutils) you could using this commands

  ```shell
  dpkg-query --listfiles coreutils | egrep '/bin/|/sbin/'
  man echo
  which echo
  ```
- to run echo (GNU Coreutils) you should call `/bin/echo`

  ```shell
  /bin/echo "Hello World"
  /bin/echo -e "line 1\ttab\nline2"
  /bin/echo --help    # will return GNU Coreutils help
  /bin/echo --version # will return GNU Coreutils version
  help /bin/echo      # will return error
  ```

Comment: Not just those two, as likely each shell has its own implementation, plus then there's the non-GNU standalone implementations. On Linux, you're probably most likely to see GNU or Busybox, but of course the various BSDs and other OSes also have their own implementations.

Comment: Noted.
Sorry, i forgot to add, currently i'm using Ubuntu. 
I didn't know other implementation in different shell & distro.